# Sending data back to fragment after scanning qr code on activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am having some trouble with how I should continue my code. Currently, I have a fragment where on button click, it will open up a QR scanner activity and upon a successful scan, I plan to return the QR scan result back to the fragment (which I am having trouble with).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bundle and pass it as arguments to fragment